# Trying to install npm node-sass

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, package.json, node-sass

When trying to install node-sass via npm at any version I get an error. Any idea why? I've tried :

- updating node-sass to the most recent version
- updating everything to a more recent version and reformatting webpack.config.js
- uninstalling/deleting all packages and reinstalling

[image]

Thus, when I try to run 'npm start', I get an error "ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'"

```
  [245] ./src/components/SkiDayCount.js 1.46 kB {0} [built]
  [246] ./src/stylesheets/ui.scss 1.17 kB {0} [built] [1 error]
  [248] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 7.15 kB {0} [built]

ERROR in Cannot find module 'node-sass'
 @ ./src/stylesheets/ui.scss 4:14-163
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

This is my package.json.

```
 {
          "name": "",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "",
          "main": "index.js",
          "scripts": {
            "start": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server"
          },
          "author": "",
          "license": "MIT",
          "devDependencies": {
            "autoprefixer-loader": "3.2.0",
            "babel-cli": "6.18.0",
            "babel-loader": "6.2.5",
            "babel-preset-latest": "6.16.0",
            "babel-preset-react": "6.16.0",
            "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.16.0",
            "css-loader": "0.25.0",
            "json-loader": "0.5.4",
            "node-sass": "3.10.1",
            "sass-loader": "4.0.2",
            "style-loader": "0.13.1",
            "webpack": "1.13.3",
            "webpack-dev-server": "1.16.2"
          },
          "dependencies": {
            "react": "15.3.2",
            "react-dom": "15.3.2"
          }  
        }
```

Comment: Try the complete log as mentioned in the error

Comment: try with `sudo npm install...` maybe that's permissions issue.

Comment: Maybe this will help 
`npm cache clean`

Answer (score 1):

write these

```
npm install style-loader css-loader autoprefixer-loader sass-loader node-sass  --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below command :

```
sudo npm install --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me: `sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass`.